# How do you assert an empty list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, assert

```
def test_negative_case(get_maximum):
    a=[]
    assert get_maximum (1,3,k,)== None, "Test case failed"
    assert get_maximum(a)== None, "Test case failed"
```

It doesn't respond to the test case when I input an empty list, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*How to assert an empty list?*

```
assert get_maximum(a) == []
```

or, if it always returns a list and you already tested it:

```
assert not get_maximum(a)
```

And there's no need to add that `"Test case failed"` afterwards.